# Regular Expression issue with specific string

Tags: regex, string, parsing

I have to parse an inconsistence string and these are the formats of the strings:

```
1SURNAME/NAMEMR (The last two or three chars are MR/MRS/MS/DR)
1SURNAME/NAME MR
or
1SURNAME/NAME
```

I need to catch this sequence using Regular Expression and I have built this one: 
`1[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]*[\s]?[[MRS|MR|MS|DR]+`

but for this name it works only for:

```
1SMITH/GEORGEMR
1SMITH/GEORGE MR
```

but not for `1SMITH/GEORGE`

Anyone knows what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the last part into a non-capturing group and make it as optional by adding a `?` quantifier next to that group.

```
\b1[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]*\s?(?:MRS|MR|MS|DR)?\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM3pD6/2)

Comment: For some weird reason I am getting 1SMITH/GEOR again!

Comment: yep, you want also the names which don't have MR or MRS at the end. If you want to match the strings which has MR, MRS then use `1[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]*\s?(?:MRS|MR|MS|DR])`

Comment: Yes I know that! The point is that the RegEx it's cutting the last 2 chars of the "george"

Comment: Please note that this is not happening for all names. For example for 1SMITH/FRIXOS is working fine.

Comment: I am still having the same problem :/